# Powershell not executing in C# (but executes outside of app?)

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file

#### The Problem.

I have a PowerShell script which basically removes all pinned applications from the start menu. I have compiled it to run with some arguments in a .`bat` file. It works fine if I were to double-click the `.bat` outside the C# application, but when executing from within the C# file. The `.bat` executes but the `.ps1` flat-out refuses, returning no error codes.

#### The Code.

The BAT command is as follows:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file .\removePinnedStart.ps1
```

This is called in my C# application by:

```
string psScript = "removePinnedStart.bat";
Process.Start(psScript);
```

It runs as admin (declared in app.manifest):

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"
```

---

I got the .ps1 script from this dev: https://github.com/Disassembler0/Win10-Initial-Setup-Script/issues/8

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a general tip: the first syllable in the word "powershell" is "powers".

Comment: So, from C#, you're executing a batch file which executes powershell.exe which loads a script which dynamically compiles C# at runtime which calls Win32 APIs... I'd recommend first understanding what the various pieces are and then cutting out as many middlemen as possible.

Comment: I have a feeling that you'd want to try to set uiAccess="true" since you're attempting to modify the UI with your script...?!

Comment: @briantist I'm relatively new to this so I apologise for the horrific structure. I've tried in numerous formats, adding args with c# and through .bat but to no avail.

Comment: @RiceeeChrispies my point is that this is an incredibly fragile and roundabout way to do what you're doing. I understand how you got there, but rather than solving the problem you're asking about, you'd be much better served by understanding each individual piece so that you can eventually do what the PowerShell script does, but directly in C#. In short, you should create a class in C# which handles the P/invoke calls that are being done and cut out PowerShell altogether. The PS code literally contains the C# P/invoke code, so that's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do like this (without bat file):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

ProcessStartInfo MyProcInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            MyProcInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"; 
            MyProcInfo.Arguments = "-noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file .\\removePinnedStart.ps1";

            Process MyProcess = new Process();
            MyProcess.StartInfo = MyProcInfo;
            MyProcess.Start();
            MyProcess.WaitForExit();
```